# comparing in order c++

Tags: c++, string-comparison

NOTE:THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED!thank you for all your helps

I want to get two strings(s1,s2) from user and check if s1 exists in s2.
I wrote the code below. it finds the strings but it doesn't care about the order of letters.
how can I change it so that for example

s1="abcd" & s2="ooabzzzzzzcd"
 it must say yes and it does.
s1="abcd" & s2="aczzzzzzzzbd" it must say no but it doesn't
also I want it so if a letter is used twice it doesn't confuse the order like
s1="mammid" & 
s2="ammizzzzd"
my program will say yes in this condition

PS. I used s3 and put a "x " in first of it just to put the string I'm getting from comparing in another string.I put "x " in first of s1 in the end so there would be no problem

```
    #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    std::string s3="x ";    
   int x,y=0,i,cow;
   std::getline(std::cin, s1);
    std::getline(std::cin, s2);

    for ( cow = 0; cow < s2.size(); cow++)
    {
    for( i=cow;i<s2.size();i++){
        if (s1[cow] == s2[i]){
            s3=s3+s2[i];
            cout<<s3<<endl;
            break;
        }
       }
     }
     //the problem is with the part on top
    s1="x "+s1;

    if (s1 == s3)
        std::cout << "YES";

    if (s1 != s3)
    std::cout << "NO";
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: For the case `s1="mammid" & s2="ammizzzzd"` why would this return yes? There is no m before the a in `s2`.

Comment: The way to mark a question as solved on Stack Overflow is to accept (click the checkmark of) an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your algorithm.

The following appear to be invariants, as far as I can tell:

- `s2` must contain all the letters in `s1`,
- in the order they appear in `s1`,
- but not necessarily contiguous

This is what I came up with:

```
/**
 * str == s2
 * substr == s1
 */
bool contains_in_order(std::string const& str, std::string const& substr) {
    size_t sub_index = 0;
    //We iterate through each character in the larger string, in order
    for (char const& c : str) {
        //Whenever we find a matching character, we advance the index.
        if (c == substr[sub_index]) sub_index++;
        //If the index has reached the end of the substring, we're done.
        if (sub_index >= substr.size()) break;
    }
    //If we didn't reach the end of the substring, we didn't find the whole substring.
    return sub_index >= substr.size();
}
```

We can then rewrite your `main` function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2; 

    std::getline(std::cin, s1);
    std::getline(std::cin, s2);

    bool found = contains_in_order(s2, s1);

    if (found) std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```